# jquery colorbox close affecting overlapping dialogs?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm in the process of replacing the generic alerts on a page with a colorbox treatment. I'm currently using hidden divs and a `href` reference to build dialogs for user interaction along these lines:

```
$.colorbox({
            inline: true,
            open: true,
            href: "#modalAlert",   /*id of hidden div*/
            onClosed: function () {
                $("#modalAlert").hide();
            },
            onOpen: function () {
                $("#modalAlert").show();
            },
            closeButton: false
        });
```

I use a similar bit of code to show a dialog to gather input data. I want to put a bit of validation checking on the input data. In the method where I'm using the data I issue `$.colorbox.close()` to dismiss the input box. If validation fails, I show an alert with message to indicate what the issue is. When I try to call the method to build the above listed colorbox alert, nothing shows. I know the code is being executed, but the expected alert does not appear.

When I debug the code, I see the `$.colorbox.close()` execute, but the input box is still visible. *It appears* that it doesn't actually kill the box until somewhere later in the method. It seems to me that it could also be killing my alert, making it seem that it never showed up. Is there a way to get the `$.colorbox.close()` at the top of the method to execute immediately (and kill the input box) so that when the subsequent alert is built, it actually shows?

I'm still new to the ways of colorbox, so I'm open to alternatives. The code I'm working with is embedded in some angular, so extracting a full working sample could take a bit of work. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way of addressing this situation, rather than trying to pop a separate alert. Instead, I put a message to the dialog that's already open. It works and is a better UX.